# Find all files containing search term except sub elements

Tags: c, string, dirent.h

I'm trying to make a C program that will display all the files and folders containing a given search term. The search term is given as an argument when executing the program. A folder / file is displayed to standard output if its name contains the search term (case insensitive).
The difficulty though is that I do not want to output files and subfolders that are contained in a folder that contains the search term. Here's an example:

Let's assume my search term is docker, this is the current output:

```
"/Users/me/.docker"
"/Users/me/.docker/contexts"
"/Users/me/.docker/contexts/meta"
"/Users/me/.docker/config.json"
"/Users/me/.docker/scan"
"/Users/me/.docker/scan/config.json"
"/Users/me/.docker/application-template"
"/Users/me/.docker/application-template/logs"
"/Users/me/.docker/application-template/logs/com.docker.log"
"/Users/me/.docker/daemon.json"
"/Users/me/.docker/run"
"/Users/me/Library/Application Support/Docker Desktop"
"/Users/me/Library/Application Support/Docker Desktop/blob_storage"
"/Users/me/Library/Application Support/Docker Desktop/blob_storage/6965e70b-e33a-4415-b9a8-e19996fe221d"
```

But this is the output I'm trying to achieve:

```
"/Users/me/.docker"
"/Users/me/Library/Application Support/Docker Desktop"
```

Here's my code so far:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>

static int display_info(const char *fpath, const char * fname, const char * term) {
    int what_len = strlen(term);
    int count = 0;

    char *where = fpath;

    if (what_len){
       while ((where = strcasestr(where, term))) {
                where += what_len;
                count++;
        }

        if (count == 1) {
            printf("\"%s/%s\"\n", fpath, fname);
        }

    }

    return 0;
}


static void listFilesRecursively(char * basePath, const char * searchTerm) {
    char path[1000];
    struct dirent * dp;
    DIR * dir = opendir(basePath);

    // Unable to open directory stream
    if (!dir)
        return;

    while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(dp -> d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dp -> d_name, "..") != 0) {
//            printf("%s %hhu %s\n", basePath, dp->d_type, dp -> d_name);
            display_info(basePath, dp->d_name, searchTerm);

            // Construct new path from our base path
            strcpy(path, basePath);
            strcat(path, "/");
            strcat(path, dp -> d_name);

            listFilesRecursively(path, searchTerm);
        }
    }

    closedir(dir);
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char * home = getenv("HOME");

    if (argc == 2) {
        listFilesRecursively(home, argv[1]);
    } else {
        printf("Please provide one argument");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any feedback is greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: `But this is the output I'm trying to achieve:` for what search time?

Comment: You can not reuse `path` in each call...

Comment: @KamilCuk for the same search term, so docker in this example.

Comment: So don't descend there.  As simple as `if (strcmp(path, "docker") != 0) { listFilesRecursively(path, searchTerm); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I am not sure I understand the logic of `display_info()`
- On `listFilesRecursively()` you can not reuse `path` from call to call
- `main()` should the the first function in your code, maybe in a separate file

#### an alternative

I will add a C example, changing a bit of your `listFilesRecursively()`...

- not using void() so you can return -1 for an error
- testing for `.` and `..` at the beginning of the loop and just using `continue` may lead into code easier to read
- `path` is allocated locally and `free()` on return
- `strstr_ign()` is a case insensitive version of `strstr()` for use in the pattern search

### code for `list_files()` after change

```
int list_files(char* pattern, char* base_path)
{
    struct dirent* dp;
    DIR* dir = opendir(base_path);
    if (!dir) return -1; // Unable to open directory stream
    while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") == 0) continue;
        if (strcmp(dp->d_name, "..") == 0) continue;
        if ( strstr_ign((const char*)dp->d_name, pattern) != NULL )
        {
            display_info(base_path, dp->d_name);
        }
        else
        {
            char* path = (char*)malloc(1 + strlen(dp->d_name) + strlen(base_path) + 1);
            sprintf(path, "%s/%s", base_path, dp->d_name);
            list_files(pattern, path);
            free(path); // ok with path
        }
    };  // while()
    closedir(dir);
    return 0;
};  // list_files()
```

#### code for `strstr_ign()`

I hate the arguments order for `strstr()` but kept it here just to have things equal. This way one can use `strstr_ign()` as a drop-in replacement for `strstr()` without changing the order of the arguments. I believe `needle` should come first :) an in the language: *search for a needle in a haystack* is far more common than *search the haystack for a needle* but Ken and Dennis had their reasons to write `strstr()` the way  they did it...

```
//
// strstr() ignoring case
//
char*       strstr_ign(const char* haystack, const char* needle)
{
    if (needle == NULL) return NULL;
    if (haystack == NULL) return NULL;
    if (*needle == 0)
    {
        if (*haystack == 0)
            return (char*) haystack;
        else
            return NULL;
    }
    int limit = strlen(haystack) - strlen(needle);
    for (int x = 0; x <= limit; x += 1)
    {   // search for needle at position 'x' of 'haystack'
        int here = 1;
        for (unsigned y = 0; y < strlen(needle); y += 1)
        {
            if ( tolower(haystack[x + y]) != tolower(needle[y]) )
            {
                here = 0; break;
            };
        };
        if ( here == 1) return (char*)(haystack + x);
    }
    return NULL;
};
```

#### a new `display_info()`

changed to show last access for folders and file size for regular files that match the search pattern (case insensitive). Below is an example of the output for files and folders. Note the '-' and the 'd' as in the `ls -l` output.

```
    - "./hms.c" [size: 1546]
    d "./sub/1/xyzHMSxyz"   [last access: Sat Apr 24 12:38:04 2021]
```

```
int display_info(const char* base, const char* file)
{
    struct  stat Stats;
    char*   path = (char*)malloc(1 + strlen(base) + strlen(file) + 1);
    char    atime[40];
    sprintf(path, "%s/%s", base, file);
    if ( stat(path, &Stats) < 0)
    {
        perror("Inside display_info()");
        free(path);
        return -1;
    }
    if ( S_ISDIR(Stats.st_mode) )
    {
        strftime( atime, sizeof(atime), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", localtime(&Stats.st_atime) );
        printf("\td \"%s/%s\"\t[last access: %s]\n", base, file, atime );
    }
    else
    {
        if ( S_ISREG(Stats.st_mode) )
            printf("\t- \"%s/%s\"\t[size: %ld]\n", base, file, Stats.st_size );
        else
            printf("is somthing else\n");
    }
    free(path);
    return 0;
}
```

#### sample output

```
Search pattern is "hms" (case is ignored) 
    - "./hms"   [size: 16848]
    - "./hms-soma.c"    [size: 1379]
    - "./hms.c" [size: 1546]
    d "./sub/1/xyzHMSxyz"   [last access: Sat Apr 24 12:38:04 2021]
    d "./sub/2/xyzHMS"  [last access: Sat Apr 24 12:21:11 2021]
    d "./sub/hMs"   [last access: Sat Apr 24 12:21:11 2021]
```

#### C code for this test

miminally tested :)

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>


int         display_info(const char*, const char*);
int         list_files(char*, char*);
char*       strstr_ign(const char*, const char*);

 int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
 {
     char    search_term[80];
     if (argc >= 2)
     {
         if ( strlen(argv[1]) > (sizeof(search_term)-1) )
         {
             printf("Size of substring (%zd) must not be greater than %zd\n",
             strlen(argv[1]), sizeof(search_term)-1 );
             return -1;  
         }
         for ( int i = 0; i<= strlen(argv[1]); search_term[i] = (char)(tolower(argv[1][i])), i+=1 ); 
         printf("Search pattern is \"%s\" (case is ignored) \n", search_term );
         list_files(search_term,".");
     } else {
         printf("Please provide pattern to search for.\n");
     }
     return 0;
 };  // main()


int display_info(const char* base, const char* file)
{
    struct  stat Stats;
    char*   path = (char*)malloc(1 + strlen(base) + strlen(file) + 1);
    char    atime[40];
    sprintf(path, "%s/%s", base, file);
    if ( stat(path, &Stats) < 0)
    {
        perror("Inside display_info()");
        free(path);
        return -1;
    }
    if ( S_ISDIR(Stats.st_mode) )
    {
        strftime( atime, sizeof(atime), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", localtime(&Stats.st_atime) );
        printf("\td \"%s/%s\"\t[last access: %s]\n", base, file, atime );
    }
    else
    {
        if ( S_ISREG(Stats.st_mode) )
            printf("\t- \"%s/%s\"\t[size: %ld]\n", base, file, Stats.st_size );
        else
            printf("is somthing else\n");
    }
    free(path);
    return 0;
}


int list_files(char* pattern, char* base_path)
{
    struct dirent* dp;
    DIR* dir = opendir(base_path);
    if (!dir) return -1; // Unable to open directory stream
    while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") == 0) continue;
        if (strcmp(dp->d_name, "..") == 0) continue;
        if ( strstr_ign((const char*)dp->d_name, pattern) != NULL )
        {
            display_info(base_path, dp->d_name);
        }
        else
        {
            char* path = (char*)malloc(1 + strlen(dp->d_name) + strlen(base_path) + 1);
            sprintf(path, "%s/%s", base_path, dp->d_name);
            list_files(pattern, path);
            free(path); // ok with path
        }
    };  // while()
    closedir(dir);
    return 0;
};  // list_files()

//
// strstr() ignoring case
//
char*       strstr_ign(const char* haystack, const char* needle)
{
    if (needle == NULL) return NULL;
    if (haystack == NULL) return NULL;
    if (*needle == 0)
    {
        if (*haystack == 0)
            return (char*) haystack;
        else
            return NULL;
    }
    int limit = strlen(haystack) - strlen(needle);
    for (int x = 0; x <= limit; x += 1)
    {   // search for needle at position 'x' of 'haystack'
        int here = 1;
        for (unsigned y = 0; y < strlen(needle); y += 1)
        {
            if ( tolower(haystack[x + y]) != tolower(needle[y]) )
            {
                here = 0; break;
            };
        };
        if ( here == 1) return (char*)(haystack + x);
    }
    return NULL;
};
```

Comment: Wow, that's way more than I asked for. Thanks a lot! The `display_info` function isn't actually very useful it's just that my initial attempt was using `ftw()` that required a function to be called for every iteration and I kept the function even after switching to using dirent.h

Comment: I must confess I was lost at your `display_info()`:D Then in the sample I chose to write `display_info` to use `stat` to show the access time for folders and the file size for regular files so it could be useful to others, since the same code uses `dirent` and `stat` and it seems to make sense. Good it helped. Note the implementation of `strstr_ign()` that is a replacement for `strstr()` that ignores case and can be useful

Comment: Indeed the strstr_ign() function was very useful. Why not use something like `strcasestr` though? It seems to be doing the same thing and it's already available in POSIX library.

Comment: I believe `strcasestr()` it is not standard. As set now my compiler MSVC does not have it, I used another name just in case I change to a POSIX setting. For sure `strcasestr()` would be faster :)  Thanks for pointing this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @KamilCuk I was able to solve my issue. Here's my final `listFilesRecursively` function:

```c
static void listFilesRecursively(char * basePath, const char * searchTerm) {
    char path[1000];
    struct dirent * dp;
    DIR * dir = opendir(basePath);
    
    // Unable to open directory stream
    if (!dir)
        return;
    
    while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(dp -> d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dp -> d_name, "..") != 0) {
            if (strcasestr(dp->d_name, searchTerm)) {
                printf("%s/%s\n",basePath,dp->d_name);
                
                listFilesRecursively(path, searchTerm);
            } else {
                // Construct new path from our base path
                strcpy(path, basePath);
                strcat(path, "/");
                strcat(path, dp -> d_name);
                
                listFilesRecursively(path, searchTerm);
            }
        }
    }
    
    closedir(dir);
}
```

Comment: it is funny that the inner call to `listFilesRecursively()`  has 3 arguments while the declaration has only 2.

Comment: @arfneto you're right, I forgot to remove them before posting. Thanks for warning me.